# Running setup.py install for pygame ... error ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to install pygame, but it just is not working! when I try to install it through pycharm it says it needs to install "gcc" and then says something around the lines of "Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the software update server"
when i try to install it throught terminal i get the following:

```
  Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pygame, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pygame
    Running setup.py install for pygame ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/4c/xff_cxmd0gqfjgrtmdf5wkq00000gn/T/pip-install-byomzkgq/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/4c/xff_cxmd0gqfjgrtmdf5wkq00000gn/T/pip-install-byomzkgq/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/4c/xff_cxmd0gqfjgrtmdf5wkq00000gn/T/pip-record-iqby9g1h/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pygame
         cwd: /private/var/folders/4c/xff_cxmd0gqfjgrtmdf5wkq00000gn/T/pip-install-byomzkgq/pygame/
    Complete output (218 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/surfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/sysfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/_camera_vidcapture.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/sndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/draw_py.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/colordict.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/ftfont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/_numpysndarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/sprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/macosx.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/_numpysurfarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/freetype.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/_camera_opencv_highgui.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/pkgdata.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/locals.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    copying src_py/_dummybackend.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/threads
    copying src_py/threads/Py25Queue.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/threads
    copying src_py/threads/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/threads
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/base_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/font_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/mixer_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/rwobject_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/pixelcopy_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/overlay_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/scrap_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/touch_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/imageext_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/pixelarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/draw_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/transform_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/blit_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/bufferproxy_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/surfarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/mouse_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/surfarray_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/event_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/imageext_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/sprite_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/touch_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/gfxdraw_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/rect_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/scrap_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/overlay_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/color_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/camera_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/surflock_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/key_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/sysfont_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/font_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/mixer_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/constants_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/mixer_music_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/sndarray_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/image_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/version_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/freetype_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/joystick_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/midi_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/ftfont_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/image__save_gl_surface_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/cdrom_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/cursors_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/fastevent_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/display_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/fastevent_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/compat_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/ftfont_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/cdrom_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/mask_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/midi_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/freetype_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/math_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/time_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/image_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/threads_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/mixer_music_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/sndarray_tags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/test_test_.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    copying test/surface_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/run_tests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/endian.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/test_machinery.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/png.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/test_runner.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/arrinter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/buftools.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    copying test/test_utils/async_sub.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/test_utils
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
    copying test/run_tests__tests/run_tests__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
    copying test/run_tests__tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_5_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/no_assertions__ret_code_of_1__test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/zero_tests_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    copying test/run_tests__tests/all_ok/fake_6_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/all_ok
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    copying test/run_tests__tests/failures1/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/failures1
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
    copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
    copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/fake_1_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
    copying test/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/infinite_loop
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stderr/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stderr
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/print_stdout/fake_4_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/print_stdout
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/fake_3_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    copying test/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/incomplete_todo
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/magic_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    copying test/run_tests__tests/exclude/invisible_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/exclude
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/sleep_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
    copying test/run_tests__tests/timeout/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/timeout
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/sleep_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/magic_tag_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/fake_2_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/incomplete_todo_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    copying test/run_tests__tests/everything/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/tests/run_tests__tests/everything
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/docs
    copying docs/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/docs
    copying docs/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/docs
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/playmus.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/mask.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/sound.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/overlay.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/aacircle.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/chimp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/liquid.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/audiocapture.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/sound_array_demos.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/midi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/scroll.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/moveit.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/blit_blends.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/testsprite.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/textinput.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/vgrade.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/arraydemo.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/stars.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/camera.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/blend_fill.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/fonty.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/headless_no_windows_needed.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/fastevents.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/prevent_display_stretching.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/glcube.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/aliens.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/freetype_misc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/scaletest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/video.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/eventlist.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/scrap_clipboard.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/oldalien.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/pixelarray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    copying examples/dropevent.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/pygame/examples
    running build_ext
    building 'pygame.gfxdraw' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src_c
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src_c/SDL_gfx
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DENABLE_NEWBUF=1 -I/NEED_INC_PATH_FIX -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src_c/gfxdraw.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/src_c/gfxdraw.o
    In file included from src_c/gfxdraw.c:33:
    In file included from src_c/pygame.h:32:
    src_c/_pygame.h:216:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found
    #include <SDL.h>
             ^~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    ---
    For help with compilation see:
        https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile
    To contribute to pygame development see:
        https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
    ---
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/4c/xff_cxmd0gqfjgrtmdf5wkq00000gn/T/pip-install-byomzkgq/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/4c/xff_cxmd0gqfjgrtmdf5wkq00000gn/T/pip-install-byomzkgq/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/4c/xff_cxmd0gqfjgrtmdf5wkq00000gn/T/pip-record-iqby9g1h/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/pygame Check the logs for full command output.
```

*Note: I am on an iMac and am using python 3.8.5 I just got it yesterday, I've used Macos before but on a Macbook, and this is the first time I am seeing this error*

**Thankyou for your time**

Comment: _"You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements, please run `sudo xcodebuild -license` from within a Terminal window to review and agree to the Xcode license agreements."_

Comment: i just realised that so i installed it, then i still get an error, ill list it in another comment

Comment: its too long for the comment @ted but i still get an error

Comment: @Ted i still get an error after that. i will edit the comment and change the error